# ABE Cryptography - Send user private key

Tags: key-exchange, abe, key-distribution

I am studying Attribute Based Encryption. Now my study concerns **CP-ABE** scheme. The authority make users private keys using attributes and a Master Secret Key (of Authority). How can the authority send the private keys to users ? Is there a technology or a PoC (in Java, python or any language). Can you hint me a approch ?

Comment: Any confidential, authenticated, integrity protected channel will do. That could happen over the internet with SSL (you can get all 3 with SSL, or you might do the authentication separately). It could also happen in person (check their ID then give them a thumb drive with the private keys).

Comment: Thanks for your hint @mikeazo (if you have another idea, this is welcomed). Anyway, why isn't there a reference in the literature on how to send a private key ? I have read many papers, but nobody explain how to send the user private key.